# wxPython dialogs

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, icons, dialog

I am writing a class in wxPython that displays error dialogs. Here is my code:

```
import wx

class Error:
   def __init__(self, number, string):
      self.error_type = number
      self.error_message = string
      self.choose_error()

   def choose_error(self):
      if self.error_type == 1:
         self.DisplayMessage1()
      elif self.error_type == 2:
         self.DisplayMessage2()
      elif self.error_type == 3:
         self.DisplayMessage3()
      elif self.error_type == 4:
         self.DisplayMessage4()

   def DisplayMessage1(self):
      dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, self.error_message, 'Info', wx.OK)
      dial.ShowModal()

   def DisplayMessage2(self):
      dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, self.error_message, 'Error', wx.OK | 
         wx.ICON_ERROR)
      dial.ShowModal()

   def DisplayMessage3(self):
      dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, self.error_message, 'Question', 
         wx.YES_NO | wx.NO_DEFAULT | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
      dial.ShowModal()

   def DisplayMessage4(self):
      dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, self.error_message, 'Warning', wx.OK | 
         wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
      dial.ShowModal()
```

How can change the default icons used to the custom ones?? I tried to replace them with wx.Icon but it did not work. Are dialogs in wxPython limited to the icons I used above? On  Mac OS X they do not seem to display correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments like `wx.ICON_ERROR` or `wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION` are not real icons, but rather integer flags for `wx.MessageDialog` constructor. Those message dialogs are rendered natively with operating system calls, so they look differently e.g. on Windows and Mac OS X.

As wxWidgets was designed for Windows API, `MessageDialog` arguments closely resemble Windows API [MessageBox function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505.aspx) style flags (`MB_ICONERROR`, `MB_ICONEXCLAMATION`, etc.).

If you want to use your own icons for dialogs, you just have to implement your own message dialog class, basing on `wx.Dialog`.